# netbeans - Tomcat web application deployment failed

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I created new web application project in NetBeans with Tomcat as the server. But, when I run the project, I get the BUILD FAILED error. But deploying the web app by copying it into tomcat webapps/ directory works.

The web application netbeans log is as follows:

```
ant -f "D:\\Harsha Vardhan\\Documents\\My Projects\\Web Projects\\TestApplication" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "-Dbrowser.context=D:\\Harsha Vardhan\\Documents\\My Projects\\Web Projects\\TestApplication" run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at D:\Harsha Vardhan\Documents\My Projects\Web Projects\TestApplication\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FHarsha%2520Vardhan%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext2833876915741210914.xml&path=/TestApplication
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path [/TestApplication]
D:\Harsha Vardhan\Documents\My Projects\Web Projects\TestApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

The Tomcat server log is as follows:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2017 10:30:11 UTC
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.23.0
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_152-b16
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|DESKTOP-i7559
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\temp
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.14] using APR version [1.6.2].
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
12-Nov-2017 19:17:36.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.503 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.628 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.628 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.628 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.628 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1158 ms
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.660 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.660 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.660 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.910 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs] has finished in [250] ms
12-Nov-2017 19:17:37.910 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\examples]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.816 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\examples] has finished in [906] ms
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.832 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\host-manager]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.863 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [31] ms
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.863 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.894 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager] has finished in [31] ms
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.894 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.910 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Apache\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [16] ms
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.910 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.925 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-Nov-2017 19:17:38.925 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1293 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Harsha%20Vardhan\AppData\Local\Temp\context2833876915741210914.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copyInternal(ManagerServlet.java:1673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copy(ManagerServlet.java:1635)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:338)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Note:** Assuming that permissions were a problem, I started netbeans as admin. But, it threw the same error. I even changed the permission for Tomcat_8.5/ directory to full control to the user, But NetBeans kept throwing the same error.

Comment: Try to run this with directories names that do not contain the space character.  I'm not positive that is the issue but I've seen issues before with that.

Comment: Directories without spaces didn't solve the problem. The same error is thrown again.

Comment: Dude, you have a space in your username, and therefore a space in your home dir. That's just asking for trouble.  Your username is `Harsha Vardhan`. Really?  Although you can get Windows to accept such a username it is really a bad idea.

Comment: @peterh - I created a new project in D:/sampleApp/. And even that didn't help. In-place deployment at D:\sampleApp\build\web

Comment: You misunderstand. It is not the location of your project which is the problem. It is your username and thereby the location of your user profile. Open a Windows command prompt and type `echo %USERPROFILE%` and you'll see what I mean.